# How do you craft bombs?

Tags: the-witcher-2

I already bought the crafting diagram, but I could find a crafter in Floatsam to make them for me. Are there other type of crafters in other cities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to **craft bombs** in the **Alchemy** while meditating. It does not make sense, but...

[image]